# How to communicate with custom Tool Panel from registering component

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to create a custom tool panel, described by [this documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/). I want to be able to communicate between the component that registers the ToolPanelComponent and the instance of the tool panel component. For instance, pass data to the component and listen for events from the component.

I have looked online, but can't find a similar question and the documentation doesn't seem to have an example. A shared service would work but I'm wondering if there's a more direct method.

The parent component would have something similar to this code (from the documentation) to specify a custom toolpanel in the sidebar.

```
    this.sideBar = {
      toolPanels: [
        {
          id: "customStats",
          labelDefault: "Custom Stats",
          labelKey: "customStats",
          iconKey: "custom-stats",
          toolPanel: "customStatsToolPanel"
        }
      ],

this.frameworkComponents = { customStatsToolPanel: CustomStatsToolPanel };
```

But the interface to the component is

```
interface IToolPanel {

    // The init(params) method is called on the tool panel once upon component initialisation.
    init(params: IToolPanelParams): void;

    // Returns the GUI for this Tool Panel and can be a string of html or a DOM element.
    getGui(): any;

    // Can be left blank if no custom refresh logic is required.
    refresh(): void;
}
```

And IToolPanelParams only has a reference to the GridApi.

It'd be nice to be able to use angular's @Input() and EventEmitter functionality to communicate between the two components.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters from your component to the custom tool panel component by using **toolPanelParams**.

```
.....
  toolPanel: 'customToolPanel',
    toolPanelParams: {
      gridId: 3,
      gridName: example,
    }
```

Your passed objects are accessible from **agInit** method of custom tool panel component which is implementing **IToolPanel** interface.

```
agInit(params): void {
    const receivedParams = { gridId: params.gridId, gridName: params.gridName };
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but what about the other way around, from custom component back to ag-grid. is it possible to trigger custom events?

Comment: Use, the _agAwareComponent after getting the instance of your customToolPanel by using params.api.getToolPanelInstance('yourToolPanelId')

Answer (score 2):

For sending the event back to the component, you can simply use the instance of this component by following

```
params.api.getToolPanelInstance('yourToolPanelId')._agAwareComponent
```

This way you can all your properties,variables defined in your custom component

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like that using `BehaviourSubject` of `rxjs`.

> Have a look at the plunk I've created: **[Event publishing from Custom Stats component to ag-grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/iAhbyXc5bo7fGnyyNZ54?p=info)**
>
> *Click on the button inside custom toolpane component and check that the value is being alerted from the component having the [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).*

What I'm doing is attaching an `BehaviourSubject` type of `Observable` with `gridApi` and subscribing the same in the `AppComponent`.

```js
(this.gridApi as any).myObsrvr = new BehaviorSubject();
(this.gridApi as any).myObsrvr.subscribe(value => {
  if (value != undefined) {
    alert(value);
  }
});
```

Now in `CustomStatsToolPanel` component, publish the value with `myObsrvr`'s `next` method (this is similar using `EventEmitter`) once you access it with `gridApi`.

```js
(this.params.api as any).myObsrvr.next(this.counter++);
```